# Set request library content length

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I need to do some testing of a server so I wanted to hard-code the content length and do not want request library to compute content length.

The code I have written till now looks like this:

```
date = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT",time.gmtime(time.time()))
sample_header = {
    "Host": "xyz.xyz.zyz.com",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Date": date        
    # "Authorization": "not_specified"
    }

sample_payload = {
   "ci":{
      "pev":1,
      "affid":"243324",
      "sdkv":"My SDK Version",
      "prn":"My Security Product",
      "pv":"1.0.1",
      "cliid":"4fe836859578e81ae5b0a061d6949634",
      "rid":234343
         },
    "q":[{"op":"url","url":"http://www.yahoo.com"}]
}

    def test_1677(self):
        self.tc_id="gtirest-1677"
        s = requests.Session()
        req = requests.Request('POST', url, headers=sample_header, data=json.dumps(sample_payload))
        prepared = req.prepare()
        # del prepared.headers['Content-Lenght']

        del prepared.headers['Content-Length']

        prepared.headers['Content-Lenght'] = 99999
        response = s.send(prepared)
        print "Response code"
        print response.status_code
        print response.text
        print response.request.headers
```

It gives 400 Bad Request but when I send similar content-length it gives 413 entity too large which is right, How I can acheive the same in request library.

I did the wireshark capture and It shows following :

With request library:
[image: Wireshark Capture request]

With curl:

[image: Wireshark Capture curl]

Why in request library it's giving 400 bad request. I can see the payload is now going correct incase of request.

Comment: Why in request library it's giving 400 bad request. I can see the payload is now going correct incase of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the header:

```
prepared.headers['Content-Lenght'] = 99999
#                             ^^
```

It is spelled `Length`, `t` then `h`.

If you are setting the header value, there is no need to delete the header first either; had you not deleted the `Content-Length` header first, you'd have noticed that there'd be **two** headers and the typo would have jumped out immediately.

Comment: Yeah, that question came into my mind but I thought request may be doing something. Thanks Pieters. I just did a typo and broke my head from last 120 mins.